# Using conditional operator (?True:False) inside a string inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substitution, conditional-operator

I need to use the conditional operator in an array, but the object it is referring to is not created until later.

```
const guests = [
  {id: 1, location: 86, name: "Handy", gender: 1},
  {id: 2, location: 42, name: "Booby", gender: 2},
  {id: 3, location: 42, name: "Ratty", gender: 1}
  ];

const guestDescription1 = ["sitting in" + (currentGuests.gender === 1?"his":"her") + 
" favorite chair","standing by the fire","walking in circles"];

const guestDescription2 = ["singing loudly","doing handstands", 
"touching" + (currentGuests.gender === 1?"him":"her") + "self"];

...

var currentGuests = guests.filter(guest => guest.location === 42);


Object.keys(currentGuests).forEach(key => {
  console.log(currentGuests[key].name + " is here."); 
  console.log((currentGuests[key].gender === 1?"He":"She") + " is " 
+ (guestDescription1[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]) + " and " 
+ (guestDescription2[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]));
});
```

Output for each guest present should be something like:

"Booby is here. She is walking in circles and doing handstands"

"Ratty is here. He is sitting in his favorite chair and touching himself"

https://jsfiddle.net/nso6wg2c/

Comment: as you observed, this doesn't work because you're using `currentGuests` before you give it a value. As `currentGuests` only depends on `guests` you just have to move the definition of `currentGuests` to just after that of `guests`.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want is to define a function, to which you can later pass one of the guests from the list that is created afterwards

Answer (score 1):

In the description arrays you can't just use `currentGuests.gender` because that's an array and it's also not yet defined. Those need to be functions:

```js
const guestDescription1 = (guest) => ["sitting in " + (guest.gender === 1?"his":"her") + 
" favorite chair","standing by the fire","walking in circles"];

const guestDescription2 = (guest) => ["singing loudly","doing handstands", 
"touching " + (guest.gender === 1?"him":"her") + "self"];
```

and then you can just call it normally with the guest param:

```js
guestDescription1(currentGuests[key])[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
```